# How to calculate time difference in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a table with a column having timestamp as it's value. I need to add a new column & calculate the time difference between 2 rows.
How to do this?

[image]

I'm new to this & want to know how to do it please

Comment: did any of these answers work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Bring your data into powerquery, like using data... from table/range

Add column, index column

Add column, custom column, formula

```
= try [Timestamp]  - #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Timestamp] otherwise null
```

to be fancy manually edit code to end with **null, type duration)**

```
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"PriorStepNameHere", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each try [Timestamp]  - #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Timestamp] otherwise null, type duration)
in  #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. But I'm almost new to this. I could not understand the steps you said. Can you please explain?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't think of a simpler way to explain what I have above

Comment: These instructions from @horseyride are very clear and if you don’t understand, they represent a good opportunity to practice your Googling skills.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to this, I will try to help you out as much as I can, feel free to ask any question.

1. You can to go into power query (transform data) and create an index column this will give each datetime as unique identifier. [image: Unique Identifier]
2. Create a custom column using this code

   TimeDiff = if('Sheet1'[Index] <> 1, Sheet1[Timestamp] - LOOKUPVALUE ( Sheet1[Timestamp], Sheet1[Index], Sheet1[Index] - 1 ))
3. In format, select h:nn:ss and this will display you difference[image: Final]

Comment: LOOKUPVALUE is DAX code, not powerquery M

Comment: I should have specified, LOOKUPVALUE in dax, not power query. Only create the index column in power query

Comment: Thanks, danchdrezzing. Managed to get it done following your steps.